# whmcs title code how i can modified?

Tags: whmcs

my whmcs title code show beleow. i want to modified it.

```
<title>{if $kbarticle.title}{$kbarticle.title} - {/if}{$pagetitle} - {$companyname}</title>
```

i want when i go my site homepage/index page then show this code like that

```
<title>{$companyname} - {$pagetitle}</title>
```

but when i go other page like shared hosting,reseller hosting etc then code show that

```
<title>{$pagetitle} - {$companyname}</title>
```

how i can do it. it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Some Modified Mr Caner G code. like this. i think it will be work.

```
<title>{if $filename eq "index"}{$companyname} - {$pagetitle}
{else}{$pagetitle} - {$companyname}{/if}</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your templates, find header.tpl, use the following code :

```
{if $filename eq "index"}
<title>{$companyname} - {$pagetitle}</title>
{else}
<title>{$pagetitle} - {$companyname}</title>
{/if}
```

Comment: then you have a syntax error in your tpl file. Can you enable "display errors" options using admin area, 
Setup-> General settings -> Other tab.
Then you can see what is causing the problem and you can fix the syntax problem.

Comment: you are welcome. but please remember to disable "display errors" for your production environment, cause it might lead security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Please check the following offical document of WHMCS(Page titles section) : http://docs.whmcs.com/Seo

Comment: i all ready see this but i don't understand.. can you help me. please give me that code...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the template var {$isIndex}.

Like so

```
<title>
 {if $isIndex} 
  {$companyname} - {$pagetitle}
 {else} 
  {$pagetitle} - {$companyname} 
 {/if} 
</title>
```

When in doubt about what template vars are available to you in WHMCS you can always use the {debug} command